# understanding the logic of Pandas.sort_values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here is the pandas code that i did to understand how it works for multiple columns.
I thought, it sorts columns independently but it did not work like that.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'col1' : ['A', 'Z', 'E', np.nan, 'D', 'C','B'],
'col2' : [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4,10],
'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3,1],
'col4': [11,12,12,13,14,55,56], })


df_sort1= df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2','col3'])

df_sort2= df.sort_values(by=['col1'])
#this also return same result
#df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2','col3','col4'])
#df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2'])
```

output of the `df_sort1` and `df_sort2` is the same.

could someone explain please how it works?
and what did I not understand here properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

df_sort2 will sort the dataframe only on col1 value but df_sort1 will do the sorting considering all three columns, if there is a tie break i.e if two rows have same col1 value then it will check for the value of col2 in case col2 value have same value in both the row then it will look after col3 value

Lets take the example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'col1' : ['A', 'A', 'E', np.nan, 'D', 'C','B'],
'col2' : [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4,10],
'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3,1],
'col4': [11,12,12,13,14,55,56], })

print(df.head())

 col1  col2  col3  col4
0    A     2     0    11
1    A     1     1    12
2    E     9     9    12
3  NaN     8     4    13
4    D     7     2    14


df_sort1= df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2','col3'])
print(df_sort1)

 col1  col2  col3  col4
1    A     1     1    12
0    A     2     0    11
6    B    10     1    56
5    C     4     3    55
4    D     7     2    14
2    E     9     9    12
3  NaN     8     4    13

df_sort2= df.sort_values(by=['col1'])
print(df_sort2)

col1  col2  col3  col4
0    A     2     0    11
1    A     1     1    12
6    B    10     1    56
5    C     4     3    55
4    D     7     2    14
2    E     9     9    12
3  NaN     8     4    13
```

Comment: I see. looks like my example is wrong. Do you think this is possible to do in DASK? until now i have found that its not doable with that library.

Answer (score 1):

It will not sort each column independently, cause in dataframes these are related, each row represent a record.

But if you like to sort each independently you could iterate your dataframe like:

```
for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col].sort_values(ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Or just `df = df.apply(pd.Series.sort_values, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Thank for the answer. I know this way we can do it. But I wanted to know whats the point there to doing it with multiple columns if the result is the same all the time. I added two operations which return same result. Idk what am i not able to understand here:)